# Jquery Ajax Response not shown

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC call from Jquery ajax. The call hit the controller and displays the result in serever side. But nothing shown in browser my code is

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/sample/sample-byName",
        cache: false,               
         data:'firstName=' + $("#firstName").val() + "&lastName=" + $("#lastName").val() + "&currentCompany=" + $("#currentCompany").val(),
         dataType:"text",
         crossDomain : true,
         ContentType:"text/html",
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(e){                     
            alert('Error while request..'+e);
        }
    });
```

when i see through firebug it says `200 OK`. Could anyone help me?

my controller code  is

```
 public @ResponseBody String getLinkedInByName(HttpServletRequest request) {

       String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
       String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName");
       String currentCompany = request.getParameter("currentCompany");


        String resultJson = client.getNameSearchWithHelpers(firstName,lastName,currentCompany);
        System.out.println(resultJson);
        return resultJson;
    }
```

Net Result through Ajax
`Allow  GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, PATCH
Content-Length  0
Date    Tue, 16 Jul 2013 05:17:18 GMT
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1`

Normal URL Submit
`Content-Length 640
Content-Type    text/html
Date    Tue, 16 Jul 2013 05:14:21 GMT
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1`

Comment: just a side note, u might have misspelt `contentType` (note the first letter is in lower case) :)

Comment: If you can see the response code in Firebug you can also see the response. What is it?

Comment: sorry. It also could not solve my problem

Comment: @MikeW it says 200 ok. the result prints in server console but not get in ajax success

Comment: Look at the `Net` tab in Firebug. It will tell you exactly what has been sent to the server, and what has come back.

Comment: Paste code for your controller also. Might be some filter is causing the issue and sending blank response

Comment: @ZahidRiaz It does not return blank response. It will print the results in console

Comment: @ZahidRiaz please see my controller code

Comment: hm... Use console.log(data) instead of alert. This will print the response to your firebug console.  

use dataType : 'json' in your ajax request.

Comment: @ZahidRiaz it will goes to the error function only

Comment: don't use ContentType property. Instead use dataType: 'json' in your ajax request. Also don't use cross domain property because you are using the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

you have made mistake passing values

values should be passed like this

```
data: { name: "value", location: "value" }
```

## **JS**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/sample/sample-byName",
    cache: false,               
    data:{firstName:$("#firstName").val() 
        ,lastName:$("#lastName").val(),
        currentCompany:$("#currentCompany").val()
    },
    dataType:"text",
    crossDomain : true,
    ContentType:"text/html",
    success: function(data){
    alert(data);
    },
    error: function(e){                     
    alert('Error while request..'+e);
    }
});
```

Comment: This is not even an answer

Comment: oh man i tried to help and i have shown the correct way of passing the values http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I see that. But question is not about how to pass parameters correctly :)

Comment: i think if variables are not passed correctly how do you expect to give it output ?

Comment: @TusharGupta we can send the input this way also